# write lucene query in xmlparser format

Tags: lucene

When I write a query using `query.toString()`, I get its string representation in a format readable by `QueryParser`, something like

```
+value:trump +value:president +score:[0 TO 20]
```

How can I (for debugging purposes) print a query in a format which will be accepted by `XmlQueryParser`?

Something like

```
<BooleanQuery>
  <Clause fieldName="value" occurs="must">
    <TermQuery>trump</TermQuery>
  </Clause>
  <Clause fieldName="value" occurs="must">
    <TermQuery>president</TermQuery>
  </Clause>
  <Clause fieldName="score" occurs="must">
    <NumericRangeQuery type="int" lowerTerm="0" upperTerm="20" />
  </Clause>
</BooleanQuery>
```